# Make SumIf ignore words?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

```
=SUMIF(E3:E,"YES",C3:C)
```

The above formula works in adding the numbers in C if the corresponding E cell is "YES", however my cells in C have "# MINS" in them, is there a way to make SumIf ignore words and only add the number?

SCREENSHOT OF SPREADSHEET: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/358381825246101505/488443165364322327/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: @ForwardEd All the cells contain a number then " MINS", so every one would return text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get rid of the MINS. You can use Find & Replace or Text to Columns, etc.
2. Create a custom number format of `0 \M\I\N\S`.
3. Use your original formula.

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

```
=SUMIF(E:E,"YES",C:C)
```

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=SUMIF(E3:E,"YES",C3:C)
```

[Shareable link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GDEW6dHuoGAN_wjBcN27sdBbHA0wzaqPccRNQDHmR90/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't really want to remove the MINS, I'd rather use a solution that just ignores the " MINS" if possible

Comment: You aren't getting rid of them; you are replacing strings that are fouling up your calculations with a custom number format that will not foul up your calculations. It will look identical.

Comment: Just gives me 0 for some reason

Comment: See link added above.

Comment: Ahhh I just realized I'm supposed to remove the MINS I add 'cause it adds it for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using Google Spreadsheets, you have the possibility to format the numbers as you want.
In the cells, store the numbers only so that SUMIF will work, then create a custom number format: in the toolbar - Format - Number - More Formats - Custom number format - type in `# “MINS”`.

Comment: It always says 0

Comment: It probably means that you didn’t set up the format right. Make sure you select the target cells (column C) before you apply the custom number format and that you remove the “ MINS” part from all the cells that you are trying to sum.

Comment: Thanks, you and Jeeped helped me find my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(C3:C5,LEN(C3:C5)-LEN(" mins"))*(D3:D5="yes"))
```

[image]

This is an array like calculation.  As such full column references may bog your computer down with excess calculations.

Comment: Error
Function LEFT parameter 2 value is negative. It should be positive or zero.

Comment: That is because you applied it to a cell that did was either empty or all the characters in the cell were less than the number of characters in " mins"